# Next js show a loading state untill page full loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a page with `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` I have noticed that loading the page takes some time and until nothing is showing in the front-end. I want to show the simple text "Please wait until page is loading..." to my users for a better user experience. How do I achieve this with next.js?

this is my code structure

```
export const getStaticProps = async(path)=> {}

export const getStaticPaths = async()=> {}

export default MyPage (props) => {

}
```

I want to know the loading state and do something like this

```
if(loading){
return <p>Please wait until page is loading...</p>
}
```

Comment: does it take time in development mode or production?

Comment: production mode

Comment: I had a similar issue once and solved it with nprogress package, you can look to that link, https://learnjsx.com/category/4/posts/nextjs-nprogress

Comment: @SCHYNSAnthony that's a good solution but he is using `getStaticProps` and this means that the page is pre-rendered at build time and cached so maybe there is something wrong there?

Comment: The solution I propose is useful for getServerSideProps indeed, perhaps I don't see why you would have a loading on getStaticProps since the page is already build and cached and so it will display very fast

Comment: Pages that use `getStaticPaths`/`getStaticProps` are statically generated at build time. Unless you're using `fallback: 'blocking'` in `getStaticPaths` and are loading a page that hasn't been generated at build time, there shouldn't be any delay from Next.js side to serve the page. Can you show us the code you have inside `getStaticPaths`?

Answer (score -1):

All Next.js pages with `getStaticPaths/Props` are pre-built and hence load instantly, so your server or internet must be slow if the pages aren't loading instantly. If you use `getServerSideProps`, those pages are rendered on the server on the go, so there's no way to achieve this with SSR either, and it also would make little sense as you'd have to send the user 2 different HTML documents which would be slower than just sending the actual server-side rendered page.

A loading screen functionality like you described will only be achievable with simple client-side fetching/rendering as you'd do with a classic create-react-app site, without using any Next.js features.